# pySpark windows partition sortby instead of order by (exclamation marks)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

this is my current dataset

```
+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+
|session_id|           timestamp|  item_id|category|
+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+
|         1|2014-04-07 10:51:...|214536502|       0|
|         1|2014-04-07 10:54:...|214536500|       0|
|         1|2014-04-07 10:54:...|214536506|       0|
|         1|2014-04-07 10:57:...|214577561|       0|
|         2|2014-04-07 13:56:...|214662742|       0|
|         2|2014-04-07 13:57:...|214662742|       0|
|         2|2014-04-07 13:58:...|214825110|       0|
|         2|2014-04-07 13:59:...|214757390|       0|
|         2|2014-04-07 14:00:...|214757407|       0|
|         2|2014-04-07 14:02:...|214551617|       0|
|         3|2014-04-02 13:17:...|214716935|       0|
|         3|2014-04-02 13:26:...|214774687|       0|
|         3|2014-04-02 13:30:...|214832672|       0|
|         4|2014-04-07 12:09:...|214836765|       0|
|         4|2014-04-07 12:26:...|214706482|       0|
|         6|2014-04-06 16:58:...|214701242|       0|
|         6|2014-04-06 17:02:...|214826623|       0|
|         7|2014-04-02 06:38:...|214826835|       0|
|         7|2014-04-02 06:39:...|214826715|       0|
|         8|2014-04-06 08:49:...|214838855|       0|
+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+
```

I want to get the difference between the timestamp of the current row and the timestamp of the previous row.
so I converted the time stamp as follows

```
data = data.withColumn('time_seconds',data.timestamp.astype('Timestamp').cast("long"))
data.show()
```

next, I tried the following

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("session_id")

data = data.withColumn("prev_value", F.lag(data.time_seconds).over(my_window))
data = data.withColumn("diff", F.when(F.isnull(data.time_seconds - data.prev_value), 0)
                              .otherwise(data.time_seconds - data.prev_value))

data.show()
```

this is what I got

```
+----------+-----------+---------+--------+------------+----------+--------+
|session_id|  timestamp|  item_id|category|time_seconds|prev_value|    diff|
+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+------------+----------+
|         1|2014-04-07 |214536502|       0|  1396831869|      null|       0|
|         1|2014-04-07 |214536500|       0|  1396832049|1396831869|     180|
|         1|2014-04-07 |214536506|       0|  1396832086|1396832049|      37|
|         1|2014-04-07 |214577561|       0|  1396832220|1396832086|     134|
|  10000001|2014-09-08 |214854230|       S|  1410136538|1396832220|13304318|
|  10000001|2014-09-08 |214556216|       S|  1410136820|1410136538|     282|
|  10000001|2014-09-08 |214556212|       S|  1410136836|1410136820|      16|
|  10000001|2014-09-08 |214854230|       S|  1410136872|1410136836|      36|
|  10000001|2014-09-08 |214854125|       S|  1410137314|1410136872|     442|
|  10000002|2014-09-08 |214849322|       S|  1410167451|1410137314|   30137|
|  10000002|2014-09-08 |214838094|       S|  1410167611|1410167451|     160|
|  10000002|2014-09-08 |214714721|       S|  1410167694|1410167611|      83|
|  10000002|2014-09-08 |214853711|       S|  1410168818|1410167694|    1124|
|  10000003|2014-09-05 |214853090|       3|  1409880735|1410168818| -288083|
|  10000003|2014-09-05 |214851326|       3|  1409880865|1409880735|     130|
|  10000003|2014-09-05 |214853094|       3|  1409881043|1409880865|     178|
|  10000004|2014-09-05 |214853090|       3|  1409886885|1409881043|    5842|
|  10000004|2014-09-05 |214851326|       3|  1409889318|1409886885|    2433|
|  10000004|2014-09-05 |214853090|       3|  1409889388|1409889318|      70|
|  10000004|2014-09-05 |214851326|       3|  1409889428|1409889388|      40|
+----------+--------------------+---------+--------+------------+----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I was hoping that the session Id came out in order of numerical sequence instead of what that gave me...

is there anyway to make the session id come out in numerical order (as in 1,2,3.....) instead of (1,100001......)
thank you so much
​

Comment: I tried changing the values of partition by and order by but it made it worse

Comment: do you want to partitionBy session_id or orderBy session_id ?

Comment: orderBy session_id